# Unwanted whitespace between plot title and subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, suptitle

I've 2 subplots in a single row. Below is the code:-

```
plt.suptitle('Water Vapor Count for Fani before landfall') #Overall plot title.

fig,(ax1,ax2)=plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2,figsize=(15,15)) #Defining the figure and axes
image_wv_global=ax1.imshow(wvcount,vmin=800,vmax=975,label="Global") #First image
plt.colorbar(image_wv_global,ax=ax1,fraction=0.046, pad=0.04) #Colorbar for first image, declaring the axis in it is v.imp.

image_wv_asia=ax2.imshow(wvcount,vmin=800,vmax=975,label="Asia specific") #Second image
plt.axis([300, 1000, 200, 700])  #Axis restriction for asia-specific plot
plt.colorbar(image_wv_asia,fraction=0.046,ax=ax2, pad=0.04) #Colorbar for 2nd subplot

ax1.title.set_text('Global plot') #1st subplot title
ax2.title.set_text('Asia-specific plot') #2nd subplot title
ax1.grid()
ax2.grid()

fig.suptitle('Main title',ha='center',va='bottom')
#fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Everything is working fine except that there's a unwanted huge gap between the main plot-title and the 2 subplots as shown [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HUOg.jpg).

I've tried setting the alignment for `matplotlib.suptitle` using `ha=center` and `va=top` but to no avail. Even using `va=bottom` or `va=baseline` isn't working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I am getting after generating some random data:
[image: Plot]

Just by deleting this row:

```
plt.suptitle('Water Vapor Count for Fani before landfall') #Overall plot title.
```

and modified this row:

```
fig.suptitle('Main title',ha='center',va='bottom')
```

to:

```
fig.suptitle('Water Vapor Count for Fani before landfall')
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Unfortunately, for some reason it's not working for me. I just realized that I mistakenly put two ```suptitle()```. I corrected it to just ```fig.suptitle("Main title")``` but there's something I must be missing, since the problem still persists.

Comment: Update: -  In the asia-specific plot, I made the range of x and y axes equal. I was suspecting that this asymmetry is creating this problem. But it's not the case.

Comment: Update: -  I put ```y=0.7``` inside the ```fig.suptitle()``` and got it fixed. It's now positioned just like your output. Once again, thank you for your effort.